# MVC indirect associations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am talking about general MVC pattern which is explained on wiki. That nasty pink picture breaks me. I have seen different ones but the ones with indirect associations always puzzled me. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

1 Why view has indirect association with controller?

view is based on model - that is why the association is direct

2 But why model has indirect association with a view? it doesn't even know about the existence of a view neither it needs to know?

I develop with Java Servlets and Spring MVC and I am relatively new developer I have feeling that it goes back to past to other languages discussed by Martin Fowler. Because with Spring MVC I always use controller as a joining link with no weird indirect associations.

I have started programming only 3 years ago, so I was always raised with ideas of doing things properly. For instance why would you store business logic in past in the model when it is completely wrong and inefficient if nowadays we combine MVC with n-tier where model is exactly what is - just a dumb class with parameters and getters+setters and the whole MVC just serve the UI as it was originally intended or was it not? We have DAOs and Service Layer encapsulating DAOS + some logic, how does it relate to model?

My typical model is no more complex than a traditional 'Student' or 'Car' class typically resembling tables in database(I don't use ORM at the moment) Do I use it correctly? How does DTO relate to model?

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Why view has indirect association with controller?

The Controller is responsible for mediating behaviour requests to the Model. This is because requests tend to alter several collaborating objects held within  the Model, rather than simple "Change Name" which only effects one object. Having the controller seperates access to the Model allowing the View simple access to alter the Model (Rather than the View altering lots of Model objects itself).

It is an indirect association because the View object (e.g. instance of class button) does not directly understand the controller object. The connection has to be applied afterwards (e.g. onclick callback).

> view is based on model - that is why the association is direct

This is not accurate, The direct association represents a delegation link. The View is a completely separate object from the Model object it may have to delegate to.

Delegation requires an understanding of the target object, hence a direct association. When information is required by a View object, gathering of information is delegated to the Model object and returned to the View to continue.

> 2 But why model has indirect association with a view? it doesn't even know about the existence of a view neither it needs to know?

Your View objects have to "pull" information from your Model, which maybe impractical. The indirect association between Model and View represents a callback to a View object when the Model object changes (check out Observer Pattern). This changes the connection between Model and View into a "push".